# how to declare array from multiple value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, double

I have score list from comparing similarity, and I want to make `Array` Multidimensional like this `array[][]` after I get `Array` , it will be sum columns and rows . But I don't know to declare that.

Here is my code :

```
List<List<Sentence>> collect = Arrays.asList(new File(p).listFiles()).stream()
            .map((x) -> configSentenceByLine(x.getAbsolutePath()))
            .map((x) -> tokenizingWord(x))
            .map((x) -> stemmingWord(x))
            .map((x) -> countWordBased(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    double sim = 0.0;
    for (int k = 0; k < collect.size(); k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < collect.get(k).size(); i++) {
            for (int m = k + 1; m < collect.size(); m++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < collect.get(m).size(); j++) {
                    SimilarityMeasure ss = new SimilarityMeasure();
                    sim = ss.getSimilarity(collect.get(k).get(i).getSentence(), collect.get(m).get(j).getSentence());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If 2 documents I can declare it and I can get sum column and rows.

Below the code who declare 2 documents.

```
double[][] simMat = new double[collect.get(0).size()][collect.get(1).size()];        
    for (int k = 0; k < collect.get(0).size(); k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < collect.get(1).size(); i++) {
            simMat[k][i] = (double) (nc.getSimilarity(collect.get(0).get(k).getSentence(), collect.get(1).get(i).getSentence()));                
        }
    }
```

But if the documents have 5 or more , I don't know to declare that .

Comment: and why can't you do that?

Comment: I didn't know to declare `array` if the list value have 5 or more .

Comment: exactly the same way as if they have three elements

Comment: How to declare that if they have three elements or more ? can you give  me example code from my code above ?

Comment: Object[] o = new Object[17]; => an array which can hold 17 elements

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split into seperate arrays and create an array of arrays then manipulate from there. An example as below just cut and paste and save as html file and run in browser. Hope it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
///// array of arrays /////
///// create array [a] with three elements /////
var a=[1,2,3];

///// create array [b] with three elements /////
var b=[4,5,6];

///// create array c with two elements [array a and array b]     ///// 
var c=[a,b];

///// create variable d /////
var d;

///// put element 0 of array c into variable d /////
///// as element 0 of array c is array a /////
///// array a is passed into variable d a=[1,2,3] ///// 
d=c[0]

///// proof print out 2nd element of variable d /////
///// prints out 2 which is 2nd element of array a /////
///// which was stored as first element of array c ///// 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d[1];
</script>


</body>
</html>
```